# How to remove double quotes from index of csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, double-quotes

I'm trying to read multiple `csv` files with python. The index of raw data(or the first column) has a little problem, the partial csv file looks like this:

```
NoDemande;"NoUsager";"Sens";"IdVehiculeUtilise";"NoConducteur";"NoAdresse";"Fait";"HeurePrevue"
42210000003;"42210000529";"+";"265Véh";"42210000032";"42210002932";"1";"25/07/2015 10:00:04"
42210000005;"42210001805";"+";"265Véh";"42210000032";"42210002932";"1";"25/07/2015 10:00:04"
42210000004;"42210002678";"+";"265Véh";"42210000032";"42210002932";"1";"25/07/2015 10:00:04"
42210000003;"42210000529";"—";"265Véh";"42210000032";"42210004900";"1";"25/07/2015 10:50:03"
42210000004;"42210002678";"—";"265Véh";"42210000032";"42210007072";"1";"25/07/2015 11:25:03"
42210000005;"42210001805";"—";"265Véh";"42210000032";"42210004236";"1";"25/07/2015 11:40:03"
```

The first index has no `""`, after reading the file, it looks like: `"NoDemande"` while others have no `""`, and the rest of column looks just fine, which makes the result looks like(not the same lines):

```
"NoDemande"     NoUsager Sens IdVehiculeUtilise NoConducteur    NoAdresse Fait          HeurePrevue
42209000003  42209001975    +            245Véh  42209000002  42209005712    1   24/07/2015 06:30:04
42209000004  42209002021    +            245Véh  42209000002  42209005712    1   24/07/2015 06:30:04
42209000005  42209002208    +            245Véh  42209000002  42209005713    1   24/07/2015 06:45:04
42216000357  42216001501    -            190Véh  42216000139  42216001418    1   31/07/2015 17:15:03
42216000139  42216000788    -         309V7pVéh  42216000059  42216006210    1   31/07/2015 17:15:03
42216000118  42216000188    -            198Véh  42216000051  42216006374    1   31/07/2015 17:15:03
```

It causes problem identifying name of index in the coming moves. How to solve this problem?
Here's my code of reading files:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
path = r'D:\Python27\mypfe\data_test'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []

for file_ in allFiles:
    #Read file
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,header=0,sep=';',dayfirst=True,encoding='utf8',
                     dtype='str')

    df['Sens'].replace(u'\u2014','-',inplace=True)

    list_.append(df)
    print"fichier lu ",file_

frame = pd.concat(list_)
print frame
```

Comment: Works for me (without the `df['Sens`]...` line)

Comment: But I need that function... Or are there other possible solutions?

Comment: I meant that the problem of the inverted commas doesn't appear on my computer. I didn't have your csv, so I don't know what `df['Sens'].values` are

Comment: I only have this problem with index, but other rows. I updated partial of the file, hope that's enough at least finding the reason

Comment: @ch36r5s I just tried and wasn't able to reproduce the problem, what is your version of Pandas? I'm using 0.18.1, check: `pandas.__version__ `

Comment: I use the same version as yours. Besides, I'm using python2.7 and Eclipse to run. If I do the same in the `cmd`, it looks like ` ?"NoDemande"`

Comment: @João Almeida what about simply change this question to: how to remove double quotes from the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simpliest is set new column names:

```
df.columns = ['NoDemande1'] + df.columns[1:].tolist()
print (df)
    NoDemande1     NoUsager Sens IdVehiculeUtilise  NoConducteur    NoAdresse  \
0  42210000003  42210000529    +            265Véh   42210000032  42210002932   
1  42210000005  42210001805    +            265Véh   42210000032  42210002932   
2  42210000004  42210002678    +            265Véh   42210000032  42210002932   
3  42210000003  42210000529    -           265Véh   42210000032  42210004900   
4  42210000004  42210002678    -           265Véh   42210000032  42210007072   
5  42210000005  42210001805    -           265Véh   42210000032  42210004236   

   Fait          HeurePrevue  
0     1  25/07/2015;10:00:04  
1     1  25/07/2015;10:00:04  
2     1  25/07/2015;10:00:04  
3     1  25/07/2015;10:50:03  
4     1  25/07/2015;11:25:03  
5     1  25/07/2015;11:40:03
```

Another solution is [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) values `"` from column names:

```
print (df)
   "NoDemande"     NoUsager Sens IdVehiculeUtilise  NoConducteur    NoAdresse  \
0  42210000003  42210000529    +            265Véh   42210000032  42210002932   
1  42210000005  42210001805    +            265Véh   42210000032  42210002932   
2  42210000004  42210002678    +            265Véh   42210000032  42210002932   
3  42210000003  42210000529    -           265Véh   42210000032  42210004900   
4  42210000004  42210002678    -           265Véh   42210000032  42210007072   
5  42210000005  42210001805    -           265Véh   42210000032  42210004236   

   Fait          HeurePrevue  
0     1  25/07/2015;10:00:04  
1     1  25/07/2015;10:00:04  
2     1  25/07/2015;10:00:04  
3     1  25/07/2015;10:50:03  
4     1  25/07/2015;11:25:03  
5     1  25/07/2015;11:40:03

df.columns = df.columns.str.strip('"')
print (df)
     NoDemande     NoUsager Sens IdVehiculeUtilise  NoConducteur    NoAdresse  \
0  42210000003  42210000529    +            265Véh   42210000032  42210002932   
1  42210000005  42210001805    +            265Véh   42210000032  42210002932   
2  42210000004  42210002678    +            265Véh   42210000032  42210002932   
3  42210000003  42210000529    -            265Véh   42210000032  42210004900   
4  42210000004  42210002678    -            265Véh   42210000032  42210007072   
5  42210000005  42210001805    -            265Véh   42210000032  42210004236   

   Fait          HeurePrevue  
0     1  25/07/2015;10:00:04  
1     1  25/07/2015;10:00:04  
2     1  25/07/2015;10:00:04  
3     1  25/07/2015;10:50:03  
4     1  25/07/2015;11:25:03  
5     1  25/07/2015;11:40:03
```

Comment: The `rename` didn't work for me but the `strip` one did. But why I got `"NoDemande` as a result?

Comment: Hmmm, it is strange. So I think the first solution is the best - simple delete problematic column name and set new one.

Comment: Yep, I agree with you. Or perhaps my case is different from others, after all, some others tried but not having this problem...

Comment: If data are not confidental, you can send it to my email (in my profile) and I can test it.

Comment: Ok, no problem. So use first solution. And don't forget `accept` if my solution was helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I was stuck with how to remove double quotes from index. After changing the angle, I think maybe it's better to add a new column, copying the values from the original one and delete it. So the new column will have the index you want.
In my case, I did:

```
frame['NoDemande'] = frame.ix[:, 0]
tl = frame.drop(frame.columns[0],axis=1)
```

So I got a new one with all I wanted.